# dateFromComponents returning wrong date

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm using this code to setup a custom date

```
NSDecimalNumber *salaryToReturn = [NSDecimalNumber zero];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian]; // Setup an NSCalendar
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components: NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitYear |NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone fromDate: [NSDate date]]; // Setup NSDateComponents
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[components setMonth:monthInt]; // 6
[components setYear:yearInt]; // 2015

// Setup the new date
NSDate *dateToCompare = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents: components];
```

but `dateToCompare` displays as "2015-07-01 11:31:01 +0000"

as in July and not June, **why is that?** It does however, display correctly if I set it to 5 and not 6

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I think I know why, it's because I don't set the day, and the 31st of June doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I reverted the current month back with one month, but that doesn't work because June only have 30 days, and it's the 31st today

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to set day

```
[components setDay:1];
```